# Schematron strip trailing period and space at the end of the text

Tags: schematron

Does anyone know how to remove the trailing period and space when the text node has children?

### i/p xml:

```
   <ul>
     <li>example1. </li>
     <li>example2.</li>
      <li>xyz size. <ph>567</ph> 1. <ph>9</ph>mm.</li>
      <li>abc size. <ph>1234</ph> 1. <ph>9</ph>mm. </li>
      <li>def size.<ph>123</ph> 3.<ph>5</ph>mm.</li>
   </ul>
```

The below code doesn't work properly when text has child elements.

### Schematron:

```
       <sch:pattern>
        <sch:rule context="li//text()">
            <sch:report test="matches(., '(\w+)\.\s*$')" sqf:fix="listPeriod" role="warning">List
                should not end with a period</sch:report>
            <sqf:fix id="listPeriod" use-when="matches(., '(\w+)\.\s*$')">
                <sqf:description>
                    <sqf:title>Remove end period</sqf:title>
                </sqf:description>
                <sqf:stringReplace regex="(\w+)\.\s*$" select="'$1'"/>
            </sqf:fix>
        </sch:rule>
    </sch:pattern>
```

### o/p:

```
   <ul>
      <li>example1</li>
      <li>example2</li>
      <li>xyz size<ph>567</ph> 1<ph>9</ph>mm</li>
      <li>abc size<ph>1234</ph> 1<ph>9</ph>mm</li>
      <li>def size<ph>123</ph> 3<ph>5</ph>mm</li>
   </ul>
```

### desired o/p:

```
   <ul>
     <li>example1</li>
     <li>example2</li>
      <li>xyz size. <ph>567</ph> 1. <ph>9</ph>mm</li>
      <li>abc size. <ph>1234</ph> 1. <ph>9</ph>mm</li>
      <li>def size.<ph>123</ph> 3.<ph>5</ph>mm</li>
   </ul>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing in mixed-content is always hard, but in your case you can just fix the last text node in a `li` element.

First of all, you should use the `li` as context to test the content at once and not each text node inside:

```xml
<sch:rule context="li">
```

You should add a `match` to the `sqf:stringReplace` fixing only the last text node inside:

```xml
<sqf:stringReplace  match="(.//text())[last()]"/>
```

That would be the whole pattern:

```xml
<sch:pattern>
    <sch:rule context="li">
        <sch:report test="matches(., '(\w+)\.\s*$')" sqf:fix="listPeriod" role="warning">List
            should not end with a period</sch:report>
        <sqf:fix id="listPeriod">
            <sqf:description>
                <sqf:title>Remove end period</sqf:title>
            </sqf:description>
            <sqf:stringReplace regex="(\w+)\.\s*$" match="(.//text())[last()]" select="'$1'"/>
        </sqf:fix>
    </sch:rule>
</sch:pattern>
```

**Note:** You can skip the `use-when` as the fix appears anyway only if the test failed.

Comment: Hi Nico, Now I learned to set the context  in string replace. I really appreciate for taking your time and finding a solution for my problem.